# json-like structures in Java

Tags: java

I have some static values stored in a class like this:

```
public class Lifeforms {
    public static class animals {
        public static class birds {
            public static final String penguin = "Description";
            public static final String dodo = "Description";
            /* etc */
        }
        public static final String human = "Description";
        /* etc */
    }

    public static class plants {
        public static final String tree = "Description";
        public static final String flower = "Description";
        /* etc */
    }
}
```

This allows me to get the description of an animal by it's "path" in the structure:

```
String penguinDescription = Lifeforms.animals.birds.penguin;
```

This is helpful because I will get a compilation error if I misspell something. I will also get convenient suggestions by the IDE for referencing the lifeforms I need. Before this I had stored this data in map-structures and referenced them by a name given as a String which was not as convenient.

Is there a better way to do this in Java, or is what I've done a good solution?

### Additional information/requirements:

1. The data will always be final static. The data cannot change during run-time.
2. The data will only ever be accessed directly by it's "path" in code (it cannot be given from the outside).
3. The path can never be constructed by other variables, and must always be provided as a whole.
4. Any misspelled paths should lead to a compilation failure rather than failure at run-time.

Note: I went with all lower case class names and fields because I wanted it to appear more similar to json and look more conformed. Only this single class in my project does this, the rest follow ordinary java naming conventions. Is this bad practice?

Note 2: I apologize for the data example (lifeforms) I used. I realize that it doesn't necessarily make sense with the information/requirements I just set up.

Comment: Read about Java naming convents. Class names go UpperCase. And CONSTANTS go all upper ...

Comment: Agree about upper case class names but I don't think constants really need to be all uppercase these days. IDEs do a good enough job identifying what is static without it so I would leave that to personal preference. As long as you are only storing strings and no functions this approach is fine. Adding getters would be overkill.

Comment: @BillO'Neil I agree. In the end, conventions are applicable on a "team" level. When the team decides "this is fine" ... it is fine. Nonetheless the standard thing for constants is all upper. That hasnt changed.

Answer (score 0):

One potential implementation alternatives would be [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Those give you even more *type safety*, compared to flat strings.

But that isn't a "real world" answer - because in the real world, your approach violates the "open/closed principle". The idea is: your code should be **open** for extensions in those areas that most likely will need to be changed/enhanced.

And thing is: no matter what, your collection of LifeForms ... will probably never be *complete*. There might always be good reasons to add **more** "constants.

And that means: you have to edit the above Java source code to add new constants in there.

So, on a first glance, this has a certain "bad design" smell. But in order to really make that call, we would have to understand your requirements - which are missing from the question (so far).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have attempted to add some more information in my original question. The data has been previously stored as java properties and as a map. The data is used as part of testing and is referenced directly in JUnit tests. A spelling-error in a test would previously lead to a few minutes extra to realize what the problem is. The current structure allows whoever writes the test to see misspellings right away.